# When i want to add a product to my cart i have a keyerror

Tags: python, django

When i click add to cart i have the following error in views.py:

"In updateItem, productId = data['productId']       KeyError: 'productId' "

views.py line 70 where i have my error:

```
def updateItem(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    productId = data['productId']
    action = data['action']

    print('Action:', action)
    print('productId:', productId)

    customer = request.user.customer
    product = Product.objects.get(id=productId)
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
    orderItem, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(order = order, product = product)


    if action == 'add':
        orderItem.quantity = (orderItem.quantity +1)
    elif action == 'remove':
        orderItem.quantity = (orderItem.quantity -1)

    orderItem.save()

    if orderItem.quantity <=0:
        orderItem.delete()

    return JsonResponse('El item fue agregado', safe=False)
```

carrito.js:

```
function updateUserOrder(productId, action){
    console.log('Usuario logeado y enviando data...')

    var url = '/update_item/'

    fetch (url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({'productId': productId, 'action':action})
    })

    .then((response) =>{
        return response.json()
    })

    .then((data) =>{
        console.log('data:', data)
        location.reload()
    })

}
```

My template carrito.html:

When i click on the button Add to cart i have the issue.

```
{% extends 'tienda/index.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block content %}

            </div>
            {% for item in items %}
            <div class="cart-row">
                <div style="flex:2"><img class="row-image" src="{{item.product.imageURL}}"></div>
                <div style="flex:2"><p>{{item.product.name}}</p></div>
                <div style="flex:1"><p>{{item.product.price|floatformat:2}}</p></div>
                <div style="flex:1">
                    <p class="quantity">{{item.quantity}}</p>
                    <div class="quantity">
                        <img data-product={{item.product.id}} data-action="add" class="chg-quantity update-cart" src="{% static  'images/arrow-up.png' %}">
                
                        <img data-product={{item.product.id}} data-action="remove" class="chg-quantity update-cart" src="{% static  'images/arrow-down.png' %}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="flex:1"><p>${{item.get_total}}</p></div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

The above block of code is where i have the buttons with the actions.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: Seems the field is not coming from your request body, and I can't see in the HTML where the call for the carrito.js is either.

Comment: We expect you to perform basic diagnosis to include with your post.  At the very least, print the offending values at the point of error and trace them back to their sources.
In many cases, doing this basic diagnosis will show you where the problem lies, and you won't need Stack Overflow at all.
Specifically, what is `data` at this point, and how did you expect it to contain `productId`?  Trace that discrepancy back through your code.  The output of that trace should be part of this post; the unrelated code should not be here.

Answer (score 1):

The `json.loads()` function accepts only unicode strings.
So first try to decode the request body with `request.body.decode('utf-8')` and next to load it with `json.loads()`.

```
decoded_data = request.body.decode('utf-8')
data = json.loads(decoded_data)
```

There you can read the docs about [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads)